# Hung parent while reading stderr from child process through pipe in C++

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork, stderr

I `fork` a child process which in turn spawns a grand-child process and returns. If there are any errors in spawning that grand-child, the child writes to `stderr` using `fprintf` statements and exits.

I am trying to read `stderr` from the child process in the parent. But, the parent gets hung in the while loop reading from child process. When I look at `ps -ef` the child is `<defunct>`.

Following is the code I wrote to accomplish this. I am new to this and the search on web does not give enough information about why the parent is hung when the child is

```
int pipe_out[2];
// Create the pipe
if (pipe(pipe_out) < 0) {
  perror("Failed pipe");
  exit(1);
}

// Create the child process
int status;
pid_t pid = fork();
switch(pid) {
  case -1:  
    perror("Failed fork");
    exit(1);
  case 0: { // Child
    close(pipe_out[0]);  // close read end

    // Make stderr go to pipe write end
    dup2(pipe_out[1], STDERR_FILENO); 
    close(pipe_out[1]);

    // start my process 
    execvp(inp_args[0], inp_args);
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    break;
  }    
  default: { // Parent
    close(pipe_out[1]); // close write end

    // read from child
    while( read(pipe_out[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)) )
      log(stdout, "%s\n",buffer);
    }    

    // wait for end then close other end of pipe
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
      log(stdout, "killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));

    close(pipe_out[0]);
  }    
}
```

Comment: Start by not closing the pipe after `dup2` and before the `execvp`. And post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Got an answer from a colleague. Don't know if the following explanation makes sense: The grand-children will be alive forever and they hold additional file descriptors to `stderr`. Hence, doing `read` on the pipe will hang in there forever, until grands children die. I just use `select` on the read end of the pipe to see if anything is there. If nothing is there for few seconds I make the parent continue.